# Get points from Google search query

Tags: google-maps, google

Is there a way to save locations from a Google search query? I would want to have a `points` shapefile based on the results. For example: "hot spring in Laguna". Of course a `geojson` is also welcome or other format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shapefile is not traditionally a web supported format; XML or geojson is what will get returned. Explore the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/?hl=en_GB#places). Within the results it will return a latitude/longitude which you could then convert into a point geometry and store in your preferred GIS format.